# Find the solution of $1 \le \left\lfloor \left\lvert \frac{x+1}{x-3}\right\rvert +x\right\rfloor \lt 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Find the solution of $$1 \le \left\lfloor \left\lvert \frac{x+1}{x-3}\right\rvert +x\right\rfloor \lt 2$$
My try:

The only thing i know is that $$\left\lfloor \left\lvert \frac{x+1}{x-3}\right\rvert +x\right\rfloor \in \Bbb Z$$
so 
$$\left\lfloor \left\lvert \frac{x+1}{x-3}\right\rvert +x\right\rfloor = 1$$

but i don't know how to continue.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $1 \leq \lfloor x \rfloor <2$ iff  $1 \leq x <2$ so you have to solve $1-x \leq |\frac {1+x} {x-3}| < 2-x$. Consider the cases $\frac {1+x} {x-3}>0$ and $\frac {1+x} {x-3} \leq 0$ separately.